# Passing Objects from Views/Javascript to MVC Action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I am using MVC.
I have a view model which contains a Business object.

I need to post this Business Object back to a controller action using AJAX.

For now, I am using Url.Action function to create my request Url for AJAX and pass the Business Object id as a request parameter to the action. I then have to retrieve the object from the database to use it.

Is there a way (using Json) to pass this object as an Object? The object is shown below

```
public class BusinessObject : BaseBusinessObject
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IDictionary Data { get; set; }
    public virtual IDictionary Collections { get; set; }
}
```

The controller action should ideally have a deifinition like ...

```
public ActionResult DOThis(BusinessObject bo) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is FORM Binding, there are lot of resources available, [This](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/binding-in-asp-net-mvc/)  link gives you some insight.

Comment: Custom Binding is very helpful to bind your forms to some very complex models.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the JsonResult for going from the server to the client. http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=399#start

The DefaultModelBinder will take care of the binding to the server.  There is also a section in this page talking about calling from JQuery to the server and getting back the JsonResult.

Hope this helps!